# Dotcover report (nunit) not covering all classes in assembly.

Tags: dotcover, nunit-console

Dotcover report (nunit) is not covering all the classes in the assembly. When I see the report generated by Dotcover using nunit-console.exe (2.4.1), I find only couple of classes from the assembly but not all.

Comment: dotCover sometimes doesn't cover all classes. It just says that there is one class in assembly. I have very simple assembly, and it finds there only one class. Filters are good, configs too, it just doesn't work. If someone interested I can provide an assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t use NUnit with dotCover, but there are the common things.
Did you check your dotCover config file? Probably, there are some filters there.

More info here: http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/webhelp/dotCover__Introducing_Console_Runner.html